# Trigger pipe reload without change in input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am creating a `TranslationPipe` in angular 2 that takes a string as input and gets a translation from a `TranslationService` and returns it to the view. Like this for example:

`<div>{{ 'hello world' | translate }}</div>`

becomes:
hej verden

I want a way to change the language of a view, and update all the text on the page without reloading the whole page. Is there a way to trigger a reload of all `TranslationPipe`s on a page, or even all pipes in an app?

Typically the only way a pipe is triggered in angular is by a change in the variable being passed to it. The input is a string though so instead I need to manually cause a trigger.

The text object storing all the translation text is stored in the service so I know an alternative solution would be to do this
`<div> translationObject['hello world'] </div>`
but that has less readability for the designer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `pure: false` the pipe is evaluated each time Angular runs change detection.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'xxx',
  pure: false
})
```

Consider this to be rather expensive.

An alternative way would be to pass the language as additional parameter, then Angular would evaluate the pipe also when the language changes.

Comment: like {{ 'my text' | translate:languageVar }}?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer   I have a filter like | filterargs:objectWithProperties . This pipe is evaluated only if I use impure pipe as you mentioned. However its really expensive.  Pipe is not getting evaluated when any property in objectWithProperties  is changed.

Comment: That depends on what your pipe does. Perhaps you can cache results or use `IterableDiffer` to check if the contents of `objectWithProperties` was modified.

Answer (score 11):

Pipes can have params, and even if you don't need them (or not all of them) their changing triggers pipe `transform` function.

```
// html
<p class="time-stamp">{{message.sent | timeAgo:trigger}}</p>

// component
trigger: number = 0;

ngOnInit() {
  setInterval(() => this.trigger = Math.random(), 60 * 1000)
}
```

Comment: Good solution, can you please just explain the use of math.random() in this code and why we dont just increment it like a counter ?

Comment: @NejiSoltani you're right, the `trigger` increment will also work fine. Unless Angular caches values produced by pipes and do not calculate them again if get the same input value and arguments (which I don't know). In this case, if you destroy and create the component again you may get the same results. Not always bad, depends on the particular use case.